# symfony2 combine primary key and relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, associations, model-associations

I'm trying to get a legacy database into the doctrine mappings.
All the tables have a combined primary key. One ID and one "optios id".

The problem is that Optios ID always has to be set but the OneToOne relation with the same columns causes the column "Optios ID" to be set to null. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or is there a way around it?

PS: The 'Pack' relation is optional.

```
<?php

namespace CalendarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *     @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CalendarBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Categories")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="Category_id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="Optios_id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $optiosId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="Name")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="AvailableOnline")
     */
    private $online;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="SequenceNumber", nullable=true)
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="Parent_id")
     */
    private $parentId;

    /**
     * One Category has Many Packs.
     *
     * @var Pack
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Pack", inversedBy="category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns(
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Pack_id", referencedColumnName="Pack_id"),
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Optios_id", referencedColumnName="Optios_id"),
     * )
     */
    private $pack;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="Deleted")
     */
    private $deleted;
```